# Strange bug on Chrome when combining `flex-direction: column-reverse` and a fixed background image

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox, background-image

I have a flexbox container with the `flex-direction` property set to `column-reverse` and children in that container with a fixed background image. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MasterPtato/07numxeh/2/)

On Chrome 96 (Windows and Linux) and Edge 96, The fixed background clips off at about 100px from the top of the viewport (you may have to change the height of the viewport to see this effect).
[image]

On Firefox, the desired result is shown.
[image]

This seems to be a Chromium-specific bug that I have not found any discussion about based on these parameters alone (although my example might be over constraining the bug).

Is there any way to circumvent this problem for Chromium-based browsers?